# How to aggregate the results from different machine in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have to run 1200 users to support my application.

We are running from 4 different machines and from Each machine we are running 300 users.

From Each machine we are getting .jtl files and it is size more than 300 MB..

we are able to get the Aggregate report by adding Listeners and browsing that .jtl files.

Due to the size of jtl files, every one has aggregate csv files only from 4 machine.

```
              Label    #Samples Average Median  90% Line    95% Line    99% Line    Min Max    Error %  Throughput  Received KB/sec Sent KB/sec

(Machine 1)    TOTAL    34114   7200    1747    11853       60155       80773       0   240417  12.18%  14.61536    144.66            23.35

(Machine 2)    TOTAL    35537   7927    1758    24698       60550       76834       0   150719  15.33%  14.79504    140.71            23.06

(Machine 3)    TOTAL    34447   7189    1750    12280       60220       76963       0   155425  12.24%  14.72585    145.78            23.55    

(Machine 4)    TOTAL    34454   7316    1748    13595       60557       76975       0   150490  12.60%  14.69896    144.45            23.35

Eg.., Average = (7200+7927+7189+7316)/4 = 7408
```

How to present as a `single` report?

It is just some up all columns from 4 machines and divided by is the only way..If it is present in a way, is it correct report?

Or any other way?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch to running your test in [Distributed Mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) i.e. using 1 master node and 4 slaves. In this setup you will have **single** results file on "master" host

[image: JMeter Client Server Setup]

---

If you do not plan to re-run your test in future and would just like to convert 4 results files into a single "uber" results file you can use [Merge Results](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) tool which main use case is to compare results of different test runs, however you can use it to combine multiple results files into one, just use the same Prefix Label.

You can install Merge Results tool using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager Merge Results]

Comment: Getting following error . ?:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Label"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
 at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
 at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
 at org.apache.jmeter.save.CSVSaveService.makeResultFromDelimitedString(CSVSaveService.java:249) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
 ... 40 more

Comment: It seems that it is not expecting aggregate report.. Aggregate report format is in the original post. .but if delete label, and starts with #samples getting at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "# Samples"
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
 at org.apache.jmeter.save.CSVSaveService.makeResultFromDelimitedString(CSVSaveService.java:237) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]